# Pointer to class with only static methods

Tags: c++, static-methods, allocator

Is there a way to obtain a pointer to a class consisting of only static methods? There are no member variables.

I have a vector class using a `typename alloc = allocator<T>` as one of the template arguments. the `allocator<T>` template class is purely made of static methods. I intend to implement a `get_allocator` method which provides access to the methods of a given vectors allocator. E.g. so that this works:

```
int main() {
    custom::vector<int> my_vector(10); // custom int-vector of initial size and capacity 10
    
    // use my_vector's allocator<int> instead of new (don't ask why)
    int* my_array = my_vector.get_allocator()->allocate(5); 
    // ^^ rhs should produce same result as new int[5]. allocator<T>::allocate uses ::operator new.
}
```

Inside `custom::vector` I have this method:

```
alloc* get_allocator() {
    return &alloc
}
```

This throws MSVC **Compiler error 2275: 'alloc': illegal use of this type as an expression**
Prefixing `typename` to the signature doesn't help.

Allocator class looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class allocator : public mem_core::base_allocator<T> {
public:

    using value_type = T;
    using T_ptr = T*;
    using T_ref = T&;

    static T_ptr address(T_ref value) noexcept {
        return mem_core::addressof<T>(value);
    }

    static void deallocate(T_ptr const ptr, const size_t& count) {
        mem_core::deallocate<T>(ptr, count);
    }

    static T_ptr allocate(const size_t& amount) {
        return mem_core::allocate<T>(amount);
    }
private:
    allocator() = default;
};
```

Comment: What specifically do you want to achieve doing so? How do you want to use such pointer in practice? I am pretty sure, you're trying to solve a XY problem here.

Comment: I would like to point out, that if you are implementing a drop in for `std::vector`, then you should be aware that `get_allocator` is meant to return an `allocator_type` by value. So, if you conform, your "pointer out of thin air" problem goes away.

Comment: You can't take the address of a type. Types don't exist.

Comment: The goal is to make `generic_vector.get_allocator()` where `generic_vector` is of type `T` to be equal to simply writing `custom::allocator<T>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a pointer to a type (e.g. `&int`), only to objects of a type. So either create an object and return a pointer to it, or use the static functions directly through the type:

`custom::vector<int>::alloc::allocate(5)`.

Comment: This does provide the same functionality, so thanks! One note: this solution requires a typedef for alloc. I just used `typedef alloc allocator`, subsequently `custom::vector<int>::allocator::allocate(5)`